# Как подключить Dependencies к NuGet в проекте?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как подключить Dependencies к NuGet  в проекте?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
NuGet создавал, как описано в доках майкрософт [Создание и публикация пакета NuGet с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli) под Net Standard 2.0.
Необходимо видеть в Dependencie эти референсы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CarrierSpeedProcessor.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FreeLibrary\Apex.FreeLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Diascan.DataViews.DataProviders">
      <HintPath>..\DiascanDataProviders\Diascan.DataViews.DataProviders.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Diascan.Utils.Maths">
      <HintPath>..\DiascanDataProviders\Diascan.Utils.Maths.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Легко и просто. Укажите ваши зависимости в проекте и они будут отображаться/устанавливаться при установке. Условно говоря, все NuGet пакеты (как и внутренние проекты) на которые ссылается проект, придут туда автоматически(отобразятся и попытаются установиться). Вы можете разархивировать получившийся .nupkg и посмотреть как он создал NUSPEC файл. Это и есть та информация, что вы видите при установки. Если совсем не понятно - могу набросать код.

Пример:

[image: Пример проекта]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пытался указать зависимости еще раз через Add References, Add Connected Service, Manage NuGet Packages и т.д. Ничего не выходит(. При разархивирования .nupkg выходит какой-то непонятный код, как при программировании микропроцессоров.

Comment: Должны ли вообще быть прописаны Dependencies, например, для такой малой либы?

Comment: @СергейЕршов покажите Ваш csproj (часть, где находятся ссылки на проекты и пакеты). Про .nupkg - переименуйте его в zip и распакуйте. Dependencies - если библиотеке нужны другие модули для работы - они обязаны быть указаны (иначе вы не сможете построить проект, а если смогли бы, то те, кто ей будут пользуются получат постоянные ошибки, так как в их проект не будет хватать необходимых библиотек)